Migrating a few questions from economics.SE?
Economics - Stack Exchange is closing. They have until May 4 to migrate questions. There's a meta discussion of the migration process on economics.se.
I went through their questions and found 9 (out of about 400) that would broadly be appropriate for our site. In general, there aren't that many questions, but I think there are enough that would be suited. I also think that in the interest of preserving the efforts of fellow Stack Exchange users, a little liberty could be taken in determining what is in scope. I put in 9 migration requests. Assuming they are accepted, then there might be a little tag tidying to follow.
Let me know if there are any particular objections or concerns.
Here are the questions that have been migrated here:

How can you limit excessive risk-taking at the institutional level?
Do students exhibit rational behavior in determining study time?
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/803/29 [2 close votes]
What is the field that studies community responses to incentives?
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/806/29 [1 close vote]
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/808/29 [2 close votes]
Game-theory strategies to overcome holdout problem?
What are the key algorithms for learning optimal behavior of economic agents?
Do safety features cause drivers to engage in more risky behavior than they otherwise would?
What is a good book for studying incentives?


Awesome, thank you for taking the time to do that Jeromy!

I flagged two of the questions that, in my opinion, did not seem to fit into cognitive science.

I have finished adding tags to the questions I could figure out how to sort of tag. I would appreciate more discussion next time.

Big thanks for listing all the questions @ArtemKaznatcheev!

Hi Artem. My apologies for being a bit quick to migrate without discussion. I was worried that the closing date was only a few days away, and I didn't think I'd have time to go through the questions on the econ.se at another time in the next few days. I hoped we could sort out some of the issues when the questions arrived. And thank you for listing the questions here.

How should we handle the answers to the questions which are migrated here, but which clearly have an economics slant to it?
This one is a relatively good question: What is a good book for studying incentives?
The top rated/accepted answer has a clear economics perspective, while I feel other answers would be more suitable for this site, e.g. the least up voted one.

I see this issue as well. A few thoughts: (1) upvote good answers that fit better with the tone of this site; (2) add new answers; (3) downvote answers that are in a general sense poor. (4) Tidy up questions through editing. (5) post bounties seeking a more psychological / cognitive science answer. And in general, the questions will fade off the front page.
